# How to execute multiple commands in the same node child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I want to be able to run the following 2 bash commands within my node child process

```
pushd ${directory} && git stash
```

Then based on the output, either;

```
git pull origin master
```

or

```
git pull origin master && git stash pop
```

Then lastly

```
npm install --prefix ${directory}  && popd
```

The problem is, `exec` creates a new process for each command, so the next command that gets executed, has no idea about the previous one. For example running `popd` throws an error as `pushd` was run in a different process and doesn't know what directory was stashed in that previous command.

I am currently trying this to no avail:

```
const parentProc = await execSync(`pushd ${directory} && git stash`)

if(parentProc.toString().includes("No local changes to save")){
    await execSync("git pull origin master")    
}else{
    await execSync("git pull origin master && git stash pop")   
}

await execSync(`npm install --prefix ${directory}  && popd`)
```

How can I run all these commands in the same process?

Comment: you could use cat to pipe the input into the second command

Comment: I'm assuming you mean capture the output? I've already managed to capture the output of the parentProc. I just want to run the next command within the same process rather than spawning a new child_process which is what happens when `execSync` is called

Comment: Honestly, I'd probably just write a shell script to do it, then exec that script.

Comment: and whats the issue with that?